# Knockout computed observable won't update after initializing nested data

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, computed-observable

I'm trying to implement a `HasOpenIssues` computed observable that binds to a UI element that updates if any member of a nested observableArray meets a condition, and can't get it to work. I'm using KO 2.2.0.

My viewmodel has an observableArray of **Visits**; each **Visit** has an observableArray of **Issues**; each **Issues** array can contain instances of **Issue**, which has an observable **IsFixed** property. I also have a computed observable **LatestVisit**, which returns the last **Visit** in the **Visits** array:

```
function myVM( initialData ) {
    var self = this;

    var Issue = function( id, isFixed, description ) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id             = id;
        self.IsFixed        = ko.observable( isFixed );
        self.Description    = ko.observable( description );
    };
    var Visit = function( id, visitDate, issues ) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id             = id;
        self.VisitDate      = ko.observable( visitDate );
        self.Issues         = ko.observableArray([]);

        // init the array
        issues && ko.utils.arrayForEach( issues, function( issue ) {
            self.addIssue( issue.Id, issue.Fixed, issue.Description );
        });
    }
    Visit.prototype.addIssue    = function( id, isFixed, description ) {
        this.Issues.push( new Issue( id, isFixed, description ) );
    };

    self.LatestVisit                = ko.computed( function() {
        var visits = self.Visits();
        return visits[ visits.length - 1 ];
    });
... vm continues
```

All these start out empty, and before I `ko.applyBindings()`, I get some initial data from the server and pass it in as an argument to my viewmodel, which uses it to initialize the various observables:

```
... continued from above...
    self.init = function() {
        // init the Visits observableArray
        ko.utils.arrayForEach( initialData.Visits, function( visit ) {
            self.Visits.push( new Visit( visit.Id, visit.InspectionDateDisplay, visit.Issues ) );
        });
        ... more initialization...
    };
    self.init();
}

function registerVM() {
    vm = new myVM( initialDataFromServer );
    ko.applyBindings( vm );
}
```

So, at one point in the process, I can't observe the `LatestVisit`, since the `Visits` array hasn't yet been populated, nor the `Issues` array, since its parent `Visit` hasn't yet been populated. After I initialize, these structures have data, and I need to update `HasOpenIssues` to reflect the state of the initial data.

Then, I allow the user to add new `Issues` to the `LatestVisit`, and to mark the new or existing `Issues` as `Fixed`. So I need `HasOpenIssues` to react to those changes, too.

I've tried to add a `HasOpenIssues` computed as a property on the root of the viewmodel, on the `Visits` array, on the `Visit` prototype, and directly on the `LatestVisit` computed, and none work. It looks something like this:

```
    self.LatestVisit().HasOpenIssues = ko.computed( function() {
        var unfixed = ko.utils.arrayFirst( this.Issues(), function( issue ) {
            return issue.IsFixed == false;
        });
        console.log('HasUnfixedIssues:', unfixed);
        if ( unfixed ) { return true; }
    });
```

If I let it run before initialization, I get some variation of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'Issues'
```

or, if I add `, root, { deferEvaluation: true }` arguments to the computed function call, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'HasUnfixedIssues' of undefined
```

If I leave off the (), like `self.LatestVisit.HasOpenIssues`, then I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'Issues'
```

if I don't use the deferred option. If I add it, I don't get an error on initialization, but nothing happens when I update the `Issues` later.

Any advice on how to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `HasOpenIssues` a property of all Visits.  That way you can check if any visit has open issues, not just the latest one.

```
function Visit(id, visitDate, issues) {
    this.Id             = id;
    this.VisitDate      = ko.observable(visitDate);
    this.Issues         = ko.observableArray();

    this.HasOpenIssues  = ko.computed(function() {
        var unfixed = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.Issues(), function (issue) {
            return !issue.IsFixed();
        });
        return unfixed !== null;
    }, this);

    // init the array
    this.Issues(ko.utils.arrayMap(issues, function (issue) {
        return new Issue(issue.Id, issue.Fixed, issue.Description);
    }));
}
```

This way, even if there are no issues, you're not attempting to add a property to an `undefined` value.

[contrived demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/fgsmw/2/)

---

If you only cared about the latest visit, then attaching the `HasOpenIssues` property to the `LatestVisit` is a good place to put it.  You just gotta do it right.  Check if you have a `LatestVisit` first, then return the appropriate value, otherwise some default value (false in this case).

```
this.LatestVisit.HasOpenIssues  = ko.computed(function() {
    var visit = this.LatestVisit();
    if (!visit) {
        return false;
    }
    var unfixed = ko.utils.arrayFirst(visit.Issues(), function (issue) {
        return !issue.IsFixed();
    });
    return unfixed !== null;
}, this);
```

[contrived demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/fgsmw/3/)

Comment: dammit, I thought was checking for object existence first -- gotta be more careful about that! Thanks, this works fine now!